# Cannot connect to AD using LDAP (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm writing code to connect to my Active Directory server using LDAP.  I can connect using

```
LDAP://celtestdomdc1.celtestdom.local
```

but I can't connect using

```
LDAP://celtestdomdc1.celtestdom.local/CN=Users;DC=celtestdom
```

Am I using the wrong syntax or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LDAP string is wrong - use:

```
LDAP://celtestdomdc1.celtestdom.local/CN=Users,DC=celtestdom,DC=local
```

or even this (server-less binding - goes to the default DC)

```
LDAP://CN=Users,DC=celtestdom,DC=local
```

First, the parts need to be separated by comma (`,`) not semicolon - and second, you need to use the `DC=....` for all DNS-parts of your domain.

*`<shameless plug>`*
Also you might want to look at my [ADSI browser called Beavertail](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html) which is written in C# and 100% free and open-source. It will show you what your domain tree looks like and what the valid LDAP paths are.
*`</shameless plug>`*

Comment: Thanks for the beaver tail, that will come in handy.